Mapping nested JSON Object to SQL table through Data flow in Azure Data Factory
I have a JSON object containing a nested array without keys. I want to extract all elements from this nested array, assign each element to a separate column with appropriate names, and sink the data into a SQL table. The goal is to generate a single record for each "name" and "display_name" pair.
Below is the input JSON object.
{
"took": 573,
"_revision": "8ac1368",
"response": {
    "accounts": {
        "hits": [{
                "name": "Nilesh",
                "display_name": "Nilesh",
                "selected_fields": [
                    "Class",
                    null,
                    10,
                    "Physics",
                    17,
                    14,
                    "Rohit"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Ronak",
                "display_name": "Ronak",
                "selected_fields": [
                    "Class",
                    null,
                    10,
                    "Chemistry",
                    18,
                    14,
                    "Rahul"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Puneet",
                "display_name": "Puneet",
                "selected_fields": [
                    "Class",
                    null,
                    10,
                    "Mathematics",
                    13,
                    15,
                    "Priyam"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Sanyam",
                "display_name": "Sanyam",
                "selected_fields": [
                    "Class",
                    null,
                    10,
                    "English",
                    14,
                    15,
                    "Priyanshu"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "stats": {},
        "total_hits": 5811
    }
},
"service_id": "25163",
"_type": "status",
"_version": 1,
"status": "success"

}
Below is the output I'm looking for:

I am trying the below approach in data flow:

I am stuck at this point and struggling to expand the row data into columns (see the output screenshot above). I am looking for guidance on the next steps.

To flatten the array data as per the output, you need to give below settings in ADF dataflow.

Take the flatten transformation next to source. Give the Unroll by and Unroll root value as response.accounts.hits[] array.
Then map only the below three columns.

name = response.accounts.hits.name,
Display_name = response.accounts.hits.display_name,
response = response.accounts.hits.selected_fields



Then take the derived column transformation to convert each array element into a new column.

identify = response[1],
{Blood group} = response[2],
Standard = response[3],
Subject = response[4],
{Roll no} = response[5],
Age = response[6],
{Class Teacher} = response[7]



Then take the select transformation and deselect the response array from it.
Output of select transformation:


